# Too much memory usage when trying to replace many instances of a string in an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have to remove strings from another string in a loop. I'm getting huge memory leak with this

```
[_withString1a setString:[_withString1a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fix1 withString:@""]];
[_withString1a setString:[_withString1a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fix2 withString:@""]];
```

I also tried

```
[_withString1a setString:[[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:fix1 options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil] stringByReplacingMatchesInString:_withString1a options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [_withString1a length]) withTemplate:@""]];
                  [_withString1a setString:[[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:fix2 options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil] stringByReplacingMatchesInString:_withString1a options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [_withString1a length]) withTemplate:@""]];
```

I have this in a loop, sine in every iteration variable fix is different and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` cause memory leak +0.5mb/iteration. `_withString1a` is 0.5mb file. After 1k loops app crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with: `_withString1a = [_withString1a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fix1 withString:@""]];`

Comment: i have this in loop, sine in every iteration variable fix is different and stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString cause memory leak +0.5mb/iteration.  _withString1a is 0.5mb file. After 1k loops app crashes. this is the problem.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, Steven, but i'm going to add that to your question. It's an important bit of information. :) (I know it's sorta there already, but this comment calls it out more.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not getting a memory leak, just a buildup of autoreleased strings in the loop. Add an autorelease pool around the replacement operations:

```
for (...) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        _withString1a = [_withString1a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:fix1 withString:@""]];
    }
}
```

With the `autoreleasepool` the temporary autoreleased memory will be removed each iteration.

You can put more than one statement in the autoreleasepool.

Comment: Good to know for the future. Thanks!

Comment: This is one place where you can take advantage of `for` supporting a single statement without braces, and end up with `for (…) @autoreleasepool {…}`. It'll look as if `@autoreleasepool` is just an attribute on the loop, which may not be the truth on a technical level but is essentially what you want to suggest with this.

Comment: That seems to fail the WTF test. Really, write code to be easily read and understood. Brian Kernighan:
"If you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Answer (score 1):

You are totally, totally, wrong.

You don't have to remove strings from another string within a loop. You think you have to because you can't think of anything smarter, but you don't have to. Even if you manage to save the wasting of autoreleased memory, you still have an awfully slow operation the way you do it.

Create an NSMutableString. Then you find the location of the first item you want to remove, and append the characters from the start of the string to the first item. Then you find the location of the second item you remove, starting the search after the end of the first item, and append the characters in between to the mutable string. And so on.